# javascript , how can i find duplicates in a string with the use of lastindex of

Tags: javascript

i am still new to js
i tried to do this

```js
duplicate2("sasuke");

function duplicate2(string2) {

    for (let c = 0; c < string2.length - 1; c++) {
        if (string2.toLowerCase().includes(string2.lastIndexOf(string2[c + 1])))
            console.log("there are letters that appear more than once 2 ");

    }


}

**strong text**
```

Comment: Do you specifically need to use `lastIndexOf`?

Comment: yeah thats the challenge of the question :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use indexOf(), as well as lastIndexOf(), you could check if they return the same value.

```
function duplicate2(s1, s2) {
    if (s1.indexOf(s2) !== s1.lastIndexOf(s2)) {
            console.log("there are letters that appear more than once 2 ");
    }
}
```

If the first instance of a letter is not also the last instance, there must be two.

Answer (score 0):

At any index, if the last index of the current character in the string is not the current index, then there is a duplicate character.

```js
duplicate("sasuke");

function duplicate(string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
         if(string.lastIndexOf(string[i]) !== i){
            console.log('duplicate character exists');
         }
    }
}
```

A simpler solution would be to use a `Set`.

```js
duplicate("sasuke");

function duplicate(string) {
  if(new Set(string).size !== string.length){
    console.log('duplicate character exists');
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help and sorry for the late reply my whole system crashed down haha <3